# How objects are sorted in Python

Tags: python, sorting

Suppose that I have a list `lst` of some objects.

What value of an object is used to perform `sorted(lst)` if key function is not provided? Is it hash or some id?

Comment: it depends on the object type. This is described in their respective classes (how they implement comparison).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

when no key is provided, `sort` uses exclusively the `<` operator, as demonstrated in this example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a
    def __lt__(self,other):
        return self.a < other.a

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.a)

lst = [A(12),A(10),A(44)]
print(sorted(lst))
```

here I get:

```
[10, 12, 44]
```

`sort` used the defined `__lt__` (less than) operator internally, only, not equal not superior. Sorting is only performed with `<` operator.

(commenting the `__lt__` operator leads to `TypeError: unorderable types: A() < A()`)

Answer (score 3):

Python `sort()`

> This method sorts the list in place, using only < comparisons between
>   items. Exceptions are not suppressed - if any comparison operations
>   fail, the entire sort operation will fail (and the list will likely be
>   left in a partially modified state).

Refer: [list.sort()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort)

Comment: `lst.sort()` equal to `[1,11,111,2,3,33,333]` awesome sort !